# Print statement not printing after while loop

Tags: printing, while-loop

Why is the print statement not working when I run this code? If I put a print statement in the while loop, it prints. However, after the while loop it doesn't work. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWN6n.jpg)

Comment: Please put your code in your problem description not in an image link. The online help explains how to format your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are never exiting out of the while loop.
scanner.hasNextInt() is still checking for the next integer, and if you were to input a non integer, you will that the print statement outside of the loop will execute.
I would use a different exit condition